# How to add missing styles to android sdk platform?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I want to recompile SystemUI.apk from my 4.0.4 phone. I use `targetSdkVersion="15"`. Eclipse complains:

```
No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Ticker'. styles.xml
No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar'.    styles.xml
```

To fix this I tried to add the missing styles to `sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res/values/public.xml` :

```
<public type="style" name="TextAppearance.StatusBar" id="0x010301e9" />
<public type="style" name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Ticker" id="0x010301ea" />
```

Now autocomplete for these styles works, but the error didn't go away.

Then I tried to add the missing fields to `sdk/platforms/android-15/android.jar/android/R$style.class` :

```
        public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar = 0x10301e9;
        public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_Ticker = 0x10301ea;
```

This had no effect.

EDIT:

`sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res/values/styles.xml` already contains the declarations:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Ticker">
</style>
```

And the binary xmls in android.jar also contain these 2 styles.

EDIT2:

this is where `aapt` can't find the style:

```
 ┌──frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceTable.cpp─────────────────────────────────────
 │2066    uint32_t ResourceTable::getResId(const String16& package,                  
 │2067                                     const String16& type,                     
 │2068                                     const String16& name,                     
 │2069                                     bool onlyPublic) const                    
 │2070    {                                                                          
 │2071        uint32_t id = ResourceIdCache::lookup(package, type, name, onlyPublic);
 │2072        if (id != 0) return id;     // cache hit                               
 │2073                                                                               
 │2074        sp<Package> p = mPackages.valueFor(package);                           
 │2075        if (p == NULL) return 0;                                               
 │2076                                                                               
 │2077        // First look for this in the included resources...                    
 │2078        uint32_t specFlags = 0;                                                
 │2079        uint32_t rid = mAssets->getIncludedResources()                         
 │2080            .identifierForName(name.string(), name.size(),                     
 │2081                               type.string(), type.size(),                     
 │2082                               package.string(), package.size(),               
 │2083                               &specFlags);                                    
 │2084        if (rid != 0) {                                                        
 │2085            if (onlyPublic) {                                                  
 │2086                if ((specFlags & ResTable_typeSpec::SPEC_PUBLIC) == 0) {       
>│2087                    return 0;                                                  
 │2088                }                                                              
 │2089            }
```

Comment: you getting anything in logcat?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 it's empty. Why should I? I'm not debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error the resources in android.jar can be marked as public. I didn't know how to do this directly, so I decompiled them with `apktool-d` and compiled them back with `aapt p`.

`apktool-d` puts private resources to `public.xml`, so the public flag is now set.

P.S.

With modern `aapt` some resources give me this error:

```
plurals.xml:79: error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format
<item quantity="other">%d of %d</item>
```

I tried to use aapt.exe from r15, couldn't find where to download it, so I just removed `plurals.xml` from translated folders and removed the percent sign in the main `plurals.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

you've copied the wrong declarations.
you should copy them from "styles.xml" and "themes.xml" (or wherever they are truly declared on the "res" folder) .

what you've copied are the automatically created stuff.

If you wish, you can check out the library "[**HoloEverywhere**](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)" to see how they copied so many things from Android styles...

Comment: Updated my question. What do you mean by "you should copy them from "styles.xml"? These 2 styles were already there.

Comment: ok, can you please publish the entire content (only the one related to this) ? I think I know what is your problem, but I want to be sure about it.

Comment: What you've put here isn't of your app, and it's actually an entire folder instead of just the styles files. Anyway, have you tried adding : "<style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar />" ? I don't think I know the answer. I thought it was because of bad styling rules, but I don't see anything wrong. Try to create a totally new and tiny project to handle just this problem (make the project as minimal as you can), and see if you can share it here so that I could take a look.

Comment: I guess, I'll just compile a debug version of the `aapt` tool and see why it prints this errpr

Comment: `aapt` says, it's because it's not public. See my edit.

Comment: Maybe `apktool-d` also adds to `public.xml` private items from binary xml?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal project that shows that you have an error, and publish it here? it's very difficult to know what's the cause of the problem this way.